# Can I use C++ functions in Visual Basic?

Tags: c++, vb.net

I'm kinda new to programming, but I have made quite a good library for calculating Math problems like Quadratic Equations and many other.
Now I met a friend, and hes programming a little in VB, and we were thinking if it is possible to import my functions from C++ to his code, so he can call them, when they are needed, so we can make a calculator?
How can we do that?

- Janman

Edit: My friend is using VB.net
Edit: My library is organized in free functions.

Comment: VB6?  VB.Net?  VBA (Excel, Word, etc.)? VBScript?

Comment: Probably you have to put them in a dll

Comment: What BlueRaja asked and... how is your C++ library organized? Free functions? Classes with static methods? Classes with instance methods? COM classes?

Comment: Quadratic equations library doesn't sound too sophisticated. I'd recommend rewriting it into VB. Cross-language projects are tricky.

Answer (score 7):

to use C++ code from VB you have the following possibilities:

- Create DLL where you export functions; and invoke them from VB like this

  ```
  Declare Sub test Lib "c:\somepath\test.dll" (ByVal a As String, ByVal b As String, c As Long)
  ```
- Create Com component with ATL or MFC or any other library , and reference the dll in VB project, and this solution is the best you can use C++ Com components as classes in your VB code.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
```

I don't know if this works with C++ functions, but C functions can be imported from every DLL in the path.

Comment: Okay, so I have to save my c++ code in .dll format, and then use your line to include it in our project?

Comment: yes, its like that. Please do not upvote this question, i need just one more accepted but unvoted question for unsung hero ;)

Comment: @user:  Well, no, unless by "save" you mean compile and link your code such that the output of the build process is a `.dll` file.

Comment: Oh, I understand. The C++ code has been build into an executable before. In this sense it is right, just build an DLL instead, and use this. (As a Java programmer I never thought about building an actual executable with C, just helper DLLs :) )