# Is it possible to pass a Generic queue from c++ to vb.net? How?

Tags: c++, vb.net, generics, interop, queue

I've received an old c++ code that handles some TCP/IP communication and I transformed it in a CRL class that I can call from vb.net.
So, I created an entry method that receives the Socket IP and other parameters. This works fine, all the process is working ok.

Now I need to take back the information received and process it from the vb.net application.

That's what I've tried without success:
I created a class at the C++ side (tried both a ref class and a value class),
and added a Collections::Generic Queue of my class type to the entry method signature.
(My idea was to enqueue the class in the c++ side Queue and dequeue it from the vb.net side.

At the vb side I coded the call but when compiling I receive the error:

'my_method_name' has a return type that is not supported or parameter types that are not supported.

obs.: if I return directly an object of that class type (without using the queue) it works.
The problem is that in a call I need to receive several of them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could receive an ARRAY of those objects? instead of a single object?

Comment: This has already been covered here at SO, see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866201/can-i-use-c-functions-in-visual-basic

Comment: Thanks @ZafKhan but I think that the array doesn't solve my problem, the case is that this some sort of communication, after the process is called it can be open for a long time and in that it will receive several messages that I need to process inmediatly after being received.

Comment: Thanks @IngeHenriksen I've read the thread you recommended but I think that isn't the answer to my problem. I mean, I don't need to Import the function because as I've control over the c code and I transformed it in CLR. So all the public methods and types are directly available from my VB code.
I think that my question can be resumed to know if generic collections can be used between c++ CLR and VB.net.

Comment: @user2177014 Have you looked into "Mixed Mode", this basically means that you combine Managed (VB.NET) and Unmanaged (C/C++) code in the same projects.

Comment: Hi @IngeHenriksen, no I've not, I will look at it right now. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found the solution to my problem and I want to to share it because may be useful to someone else. My project is a CLR project (CRL Class Library) is just an entry point to several function wrote in C,  and I'm using the dll in a VB.net project loaded by 'Add Reference'.

My C++ part can be resumed to:

Some class (in this case created as 'value')

```
public value class MyClass
{
public:
int val1;
... 
};
```

Some function that receives a Queue as parameter:

```
void FunctionName(System::Collections::Generic::Queue<MyClass>^ MyClassQueue)
{
// create some object of your class
MyClass obj1;
// fill the object
obj1.val1 = 0;

// enqueue the object (you need to use '->')
MyClassQueue->Enqueue(obj1);
};
```

Now, from the VB.net side, if the C++ part is CLR you will see the types and functions after you add the reference to the dll.

so, you will create a Queue of MyClass type and call the function with it

```
Dim myClassObj as new MyClass
Dim myClassQueue as new Queue(of MyClass)

myClassObj.FunctionName(myClassQueue)
myClassObj =  myClassQueue.Dequeue()
```

Now you can process the object in the vb side as expected.

best regards,